# ASP.NET 2.0 Small Application Locks Up until we run iisreset.. Help!

Tags: asp.net, iis, file, locking

I recently developed a simple application for displaying a list of files to some users based on access levels and allowing them to download them etc.

This application was developed to be hosted inside a large corporation with heavy security policies and is fairly mission critical..

The application is very basic,

- it checks the users NTID (using windows authentication)
- compares that to a table in SQL
- then pulls up a list of all the files on which this user has access

Thats pretty much it..

There are also a couple of forms for adding a user and editing a user and uploading a file.

We have a problem often where the application is pretty much unresponsive.

This can be remedied by opening command prompt and running 'iisreset'

I should also note when originally deploying the application we changed some settings on the server to allow connections to stay open a while longer to allow bigger file uploads..

Could this be locking the application up?

I am unabble to restart the server until the weekend.

The server is a windows 2003 box running IIS6.0 and .NET 2.0

Helllllp!

Thanks
Daniel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haha.. I Feel So Stoopid!

After a morning of writing the stack to log files i found the error..

```
    try
    {
        //Do Some SQL Stuff Here
        //Close SQL Connection
    }
    catch
    {
        //Whoops it went Bang!
    }
```

Fixed By Adding this:

```
    finally
    {
       //Close The Connection Doofus!
    }
```

Whoops!

So Basically if an error happens in the SQL stuff it'll go straight to catch and never close the connection!

Thanks for your help everyone!

Answer (score 1):

There are very rare cases that one application hangs ups and only iis restart fix it.

This is the cases of infinity loops. So check your code for

```
Responce.Redirect(onsamepage);
```

or for

```
public string sMyText
{
   get {return sMyText;}
   set {sMyText = value;}
}
```

or for

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
  base.OnInit(e);
}
```

Comment: Thanks... that makes sense... we've narrowed it down to one form.. weird thing is it works fine on my machine

Answer (score 1):

If the application is hung, I would recommend using tools to capture memory dumps and analyze it. That would give you a sure shot answer.

Try this... http://aspalliance.com/1350_Post_Production_Debugging_for_ASPNET_Applications__Part_1

Once you are done capturing the dumps, you can check for threads which look hung and what exactly are they doing.

[Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/tess/)